# Cannot print string using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get data from a web page and print the contents to screen. Here is the code for HTTP get request:

```
https.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', (resp) => {
      let data = '';

      // A chunk of data has been received.
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
      });

      // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
      resp.on('end', () => {
          for (let i = 0; i < JSON.parse(data).length; i++)
              cities += JSON.parse(data)[i].address.city + '\n';
          console.log(cities);
      });
```

At the code below i cannot print it to screen. I searched on Google but didn't come up with a solution.

```
let printing = "All users data:";
  return <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
          <p>
              {printing}
          </p>
          <p>
              {cities}
          </p>
      </header>
  </div>;
```

Here i can print the printing string but i can't print cities string.What is the reason for that?
(Full code can be found at https://github.com/ezinal/reacttask/blob/master/src/App.js
(39 lines))

Comment: React won't rerender a component if there is not a state or props change. I think you should have the logic of fetching the data elsewhere and pass them to the component via props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the state outside of the http request completion callback, so the state will be updated before the http request has completed i.e `this.setState` is called immediately after the http request is started, not after the request is completed. You need to move `this.setState({cities : getCities})` into the `resp.on('end', ...)` callback, like this:

```
resp.on('end', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < JSON.parse(data).length; i++)
        getCities += JSON.parse(data)[i].address.city + '\n';
    console.log(getCities);
    this.setState({cities : getCities}); // <-- update state here once http request has completed
});
```